# Luminance values clipped to [0, 1] during texture transfer?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I am uploading a host-side texture to OpenGL using something like:

```
GLfloat * values = new [nRows * nCols];

// initialize values
for (int i = 0; i < nRows * nCols; ++i)
{
    values[i] = (i % 201 - 100) / 10.0f; // values from -10.0f .. + 10.0f
}

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, nRows, nCols, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_FLOAT, values);
```

However, when I read back the texture using glGetTexImage(), it turns out that all values are clipped to the range [0..1].

First, I cannot find where this behavior is documented (I am using the Red Book for OpenGL 2.1).

Second, is it possible to change this behavior and let the values pass unchanged? I want to access the unscaled, unclipped data in an GLSL shader.

Comment: The clamping is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But I think you should explain what you want to do. Why don't you use normalized values in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot find where this behavior is documented

In the actual specification, it's in the section on Pixel Rectangles, titled Transfer of Pixel Rectangles.

> Second, is it possible to change this behavior and let the values pass unchanged?

Yes. If you want to use "unscaled, unclamped" data, you have to use a [floating point image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format). The format of your texture is defined when you [created the storage for it](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage), probably by a call to `glTexImage2D`. The third parameter of that function defines the format. So use a proper floating-point format instead of an integer one.

Comment: Ahh, you mean the internal format parameter in glTexImage2D!
Here is the list of appropriate float formats:
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexBuffer.xml#description
For me, GL_R32F did the trick!